# Why NSObjectController does not update the model property it is bound to?

Tags: cocoa, binding, key-value-observing, appkit, nsobjectcontroller

I configure bindings like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObjectController *controller;

...

self.controller = [[NSObjectController alloc] initWithContent:nil];
[self.controller bind:NSContentObjectBinding toObject:self
          withKeyPath:@"name" options:nil];
[self.controller addObject:@"Hello"];

...

NSTextField *textField = [NSTextField textFieldWithString:nil];
[textField bind:NSValueBinding toObject:self.controller
    withKeyPath:@"content" options:nil];
```

The text field shows the string “Hello” after launch, then I change it to “World” and hit Return. However, only the object controller’s content is updated:

```
[controller.content isEqualToString:@"World"]; // YES
         [self.name isEqualToString:@"World"]; // NO — WHY?
         [self.name isEqualToString:@"Hello"]; // YES
```

So how do I configure the `NSObjectController` to update the local property that it is bound to?

Comment: What if instead of binding to self, you initWithContent:self?

Comment: I think this would lead to retain cycle, but the solution is very close. Could you please verify my answer? Thanks a lot, you really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks to Jacob Gorban:

```
self.name = @"Hello";
self.controller = [[NSObjectController alloc] initWithContent:nil];
[self.controller bind:NSContentObjectBinding toObject:self
          withKeyPath:@"self" options:nil];

...

NSTextField *textField = [NSTextField textFieldWithString:nil];
[textField bind:NSValueBinding toObject:self.controller
    withKeyPath:@"selection.name" options:nil];
```